# Replacing Items in Vim without replacing the older replaced ones

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, vim, vi

We have a basic c code such as ;

```
if (a > b && a < c) {

    min = a ; }
```

I do want to know how to change "<"s in a long pattern with ">" and ">"s with "<".

But when I try to do this, normally "<"s becomes ">", That is not a problem;

But after, when I try to change ">"s with "<"s, it fails because the ones I changed before changes again, i.e , they becomes they were before

Thus, it is needed to change them at once but , for example, the vim terminal operation;

```
:%s/>/< | %s/</>
```

cannot success that.

How could I achieve that problem?

Comment: First change all `<` into a previously unused character, then change `>` to `<`, then the temporary character to `>`?

Comment: Imm, that works very well I think, thank you

Comment: @EOF,  can you make that an answer so the OP can select it and close the question?

Answer (score 3):

use a dictionary to map to their replacement. Try this

```
:%s/\v(\<|\>)/\={'<':'>','>':'<'}[submatch(0)]/g
```